# DataAnnotations TryValidateProperty Doesn't See Properties

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I'm having an issue with DataAnnotations when calling Validator.TryValidateProperty(). I'm receiving the error:

*System.ArgumentException: 'The type 'InvoiceDetail' does not contain a public property named 'invoiceNumber'. Parameter name: propertyName'*

This occurs for all of the properties of this object. It happened for a simple test Person object with a single property as well. Any insight on what could cause this?

I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.2

```
using System;
using GemBox.Spreadsheet;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace APInvoiceFileImporter
{
    public class InvoiceDetail : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Origin is required.")]
        [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Origin must be at most 12 characters.")]
        public string origin;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice Header is required.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Invoice Number must be at most 50 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[\S] +$", ErrorMessage = "Invoice Number must not contain spaces.")]
        public string invoiceNumber;

        [MaxLength(130, ErrorMessage = "Description must be at most 130 characters.")]
        public string description;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vendor Header is required.")]
        [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Vendor Header must be at most 12 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[\d]+$",ErrorMessage = "Vendor Header must be numeric.")]
        public string vendorHeader;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vendor Site is required.")]
        [MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Vendor Site must be at most 12 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[\d]+$",ErrorMessage = "Vendor Site must be numeric.")]
        public string vendorSite;

        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Customer Account Number must be at most 25 characters.")]
        public string customerAccountNum;

        [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "PONumber must be at most 25 characters.")]
        public string PONumber;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice Date is required.")]
        public DateTime? invDate;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Invoice Amount is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invoice Amount must be in decimal format.")]
        [Range(0, 9999999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Invoice Amount must only have 2 decimal digits.")]
        public decimal? invAmt;

        [MaxLength(28, ErrorMessage = "HeaderGL must be at most 28 characters.")]
        public string headerGL;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 1 is required.")]
        [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 1 must be at most 2 characters.")]
        public string seg1;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 2 is required.")]
        [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 2 must be at most 5 characters.")]
        public string seg2;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 3 is required.")]
        [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "ItemGLCode not formatted properly: Segment 3 must be at most 5 characters.")]
        public string seg3;

        [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Segment 4 must be at most 2 characters.")]
        public string seg4;

        [MaxLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Segment 5 must be at most 2 characters.")]
        public string seg5;

        [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Segment 6 must be at most 3 characters.")]
        public string seg6;

        [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Segment 7 must be at most 3 characters.")]
        public string seg7;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Item Amount is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Item Amount must be in decimal format.")] 
            [Range(0, 9999999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Item Amount must only have 2 decimal digits.")]
        public decimal? itemAmt;

        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Tax Amount must be in decimal format.")]
        [Range(0, 9999999999999999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Tax Amount must only have 2 decimal digits.")]
        public decimal? taxAmt;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Line Number is required.")]
        public int? lineNumber;

        [MaxLength(13, ErrorMessage = "Line Description must be at most 13 characters.")]
        public string lineDescription;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Currency Code is required.")]
        [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Currency Code must be at most 3 characters.")]
        public string currencyCode;

        [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Employee Id must be at most 30 characters.")]
        public string employeeId;

        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "File Name must be at most 50 characters.")]
        public string fileName;       

        public int? batchNumber;

        public InvoiceDetail(string fileName, ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int rowNum)
        {
            try
            {
                origin = "EBENA";

                invoiceNumber = worksheet.Cells[1, 0].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1,0].Value.ToString(): null;

                description = worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value.ToString() : null;

                string[] vendorSiteId = worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString().Split('-') : null;
                if(vendorSiteId != null)
                {
                    vendorHeader = vendorSiteId.Length > 0 ? vendorSiteId[0] : null;
                    vendorSite = vendorSiteId.Length > 1 ? vendorSiteId[1] : null;
                }
                else
                {
                    vendorHeader = null;
                    vendorSite = null;
                }

                customerAccountNum = worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 4].ToString() : null;

                PONumber = worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value.ToString() : null;

                invDate = DateTime.TryParse((worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value ?? "").ToString(), out DateTime temp) ? (DateTime?)worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value : null;

                invAmt = decimal.TryParse((worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value ?? "").ToString(), out decimal temp2) ? (decimal?)Math.Round(decimal.Parse(worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value.ToString()), 2) : null;

                headerGL = null;

                string[] itemGLCode = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 12].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 12].Value.ToString().Split('.') : null;
                if(itemGLCode != null)
                {
                    seg1 = itemGLCode.Length > 0 ? itemGLCode[0] : null;
                    seg2 = itemGLCode.Length > 1 ? itemGLCode[1] : null;
                    seg3 = itemGLCode.Length > 2 ? itemGLCode[2] : null;
                }
                else
                {
                    seg1 = null;
                    seg2 = null;
                    seg3 = null;
                }

                seg4 = null;

                seg5 = null;

                seg6 = null;

                seg7 = null;

                itemAmt = decimal.TryParse((worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 13].Value ?? "").ToString(), out decimal temp4) ? (decimal?)Math.Round(decimal.Parse(worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 13].Value.ToString()), 2) : null;

                taxAmt = decimal.TryParse((worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 14].Value ?? "").ToString(), out decimal temp3) ? (decimal?)Math.Round(decimal.Parse(worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 14].Value.ToString()), 2) : null;

                lineNumber = rowNum;

                lineDescription = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 19].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 19].Value.ToString() : null;

                currencyCode = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 16].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 16].Value.ToString() : "USD";

                employeeId = worksheet.Cells[1, 11].Value != null ? worksheet.Cells[1, 11].Value.ToString().ToLower().Replace(@"thekag\", "") : null;

                this.fileName = fileName;

                batchNumber = null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log($"Failed to construct InvoiceDetail {invoiceNumber} : {lineNumber}.\r\n\r\n{ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            ValidateField(results,invoiceNumber,"invoiceNumber");                
            ValidateField(results,vendorHeader,"vendorHeader");                
            ValidateField(results,vendorSite,"vendorSite");                
            ValidateField(results,invDate,"invDate");                
            ValidateField(results,vendorSite,"vendorSite");                
            ValidateField(results,customerAccountNum,"customerAccountNum");                
            ValidateField(results,PONumber,"PONumber");                
            ValidateField(results,invDate,"invDate");                
            ValidateField(results,invAmt,"invAmt");                
            ValidateField(results,headerGL,"headerGL");                
            ValidateField(results,seg1,"seg1");                
            ValidateField(results,seg2,"seg2");                
            ValidateField(results,seg3,"seg3");                
            ValidateField(results,seg4,"seg4");                
            ValidateField(results,seg5,"seg5");                
            ValidateField(results,seg6,"seg6");                
            ValidateField(results,seg7,"seg7");         
            ValidateField(results,itemAmt,"itemAmt");         
            ValidateField(results,taxAmt,"taxAmt");         
            ValidateField(results,lineNumber,"lineNumber");         
            ValidateField(results,lineDescription,"lineDescription");
            ValidateField(results,currencyCode,"currencyCode");
            ValidateField(results,employeeId,"employeeId");
            ValidateField(results,fileName,"fileName");
            ValidateField(results,batchNumber,"batchNumber");

            return results;
        }

        public void ValidateField(List<ValidationResult> results, object value, string memberName)
        {
            ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = memberName };
            Validator.TryValidateProperty(value,context,results);
        }       
    }    
}
```

Comment: Because you have fields not properties.

Comment: Ahhh so all I needed to do was set the accessors?

Comment: Obviously... And don’t forget the naming nomenclature. Properties are PascalCase not camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Legacy Code's comment answered my question:

> Because you have fields not properties.  Obviously... And don’t forget the naming nomenclature. Properties are PascalCase not camelCase.

all I needed to do was set the accessors